# ggplot y variable based on selection from radio button-shiny in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, radio-button

I'm trying to get R in shiny to plot different y values for each country based upon the selection from radio buttons (each possible set of y-values is in my .csv as its own column). It doesn't seem to work even if names are matched perfectly (as they are below), or I call it in a output$data in the ggplot graph either. Please help!

```
library(shiny) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(readr)

Emissions <- read_csv("~/Desktop/CAIT Country GHG Emissions.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Greenhouse Gas Emissions Emissions by Country, 1990-2014"),

radioButtons("data", "Include:", choices = c("total", 
"total_including_landuse", "co2_only")

),

sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel( selectInput("country","Country:", choices 
= Emissions$Country)

),

mainPanel(

plotOutput("emitPlot"),
)
) )

server <- function(input, output) {

output$emitPlot <- renderPlot({

emissions = input$data

ggplot(subset(Emissions, Country == input$country, ), aes(x =Year, y = 
emissions ###(THIS IS THE PART I'M TRYING TO FIX, it should be like y= 
input$data, or something###

 ))+
geom_col(aes(fill = Year))+
xlab("Year")+
ylab("GHG Emissions (Metric tons, CO2 Equivellent)")+
theme_classic()
}) }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input$data` is a string, while `aes` uses non-standard evaluation to capture the variable names. We could use `aes_string()` instead. A working example with the `mtcars` dataset is given below. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Mtcars example"),
  radioButtons("data", "Include:", choices = c('hp','disp','cyl')),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(selectInput("am","am:", choices = unique(mtcars$am))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("mtcarsPlot")
  )
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mtcarsPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      subset(mtcars, am == input$am), 
      aes_string(x = 'mpg', y = input$data)) + geom_point() 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```